# Jenkins kubernetes plugin with git private repo

Tags: git, github, jenkins, gitlab

I'm trying to use [jenkins kubernetes plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/) with [Gitlab branch source plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitlab-branch-source/), and a Kubernetes cluster to make a build in my cluster.
I successfully managed to make the pipeline work with the public repository, but when I'm trying to use private repo in my SCM, the agent pod (with the default jnlp container) cannot authenticate against my git server. How can I pass down the credentials from the Jenkins controller to the agent pod?

pipeline log:

```
The recommended git tool is: git
Warning: CredentialId "b4f86bce-18c3-4758-972d-5907e601efd0" could not be found.
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning with configured refspecs honoured and without tags
Cloning repository https://gitlab.mycompany.eu/myuser/myproject.git
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --no-tags --force --progress -- https://gitlab.mycompany.eu/myuser/myproject.git +refs/heads/feature-jenkins-deployment:refs/remotes/origin/feature-jenkins-deployment" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
```

Comment: You have a lot of informations about credentials here : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#handling-credentials

Answer (score 0):

If I set the credentials directly on the project, instead of relying on the global configuration, it works seamlessly.